# TNT4j dump: How to print only elements with values

Tags: java, log4j, dump, tnt4j

Using TNT4j, if we print any object (e.g. `HashMap`) in dump, it prints all the elements of that object along with their full class name, type, modifiers and value (if set).

What if we want to print only those elements who have a value assigned to them as it makes the information more readable?

The dump generated if we pass a `HashMap` to dump is attached:

```
{
    "dump.reason": "null"
    "dump.name": "{Client.Address=127.0.0.1}",
    "dump.category": "Objects",
    "dump.provider": "Client Machine Details",
    "dump.provider.category": "Objects",
    "dump.time.string": "2014-07-21 16:46:29.646000 IST",
    "dump.time.stamp": 1405941389646,
    "dump.collection": {
        "java.util.HashMap.$classloader": "null",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.$type": "int",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.$modifiers": "static final",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.$value": "16",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY.$class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "java.util.HashMap.MAXIMUM_CAPACITY.$type": "int",
        "java.util.HashMap.MAXIMUM_CAPACITY.$modifiers": "static final",
        "java.util.HashMap.MAXIMUM_CAPACITY.$value": "1073741824",
        "java.util.HashMap.MAXIMUM_CAPACITY.$class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR.$type": "float",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR.$modifiers": "static final",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR.$value": "0.75",
        "java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR.$class": "java.lang.Float",
        "java.util.HashMap.table.$type": "[Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;",
        "java.util.HashMap.table.$modifiers": "transient",
        "java.util.HashMap.table.$value": "[Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;@2bf2a0",
        "java.util.HashMap.table.$class": "[Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;",
        "java.util.HashMap.size.$type": "int",
        "java.util.HashMap.size.$modifiers": "transient",
        "java.util.HashMap.size.$value": "1",
        "java.util.HashMap.size.$class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "java.util.HashMap.threshold.$type": "int",
        "java.util.HashMap.threshold.$modifiers": "",
        "java.util.HashMap.threshold.$value": "12",
        "java.util.HashMap.threshold.$class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "java.util.HashMap.loadFactor.$type": "float",
        "java.util.HashMap.loadFactor.$modifiers": "final",
        "java.util.HashMap.loadFactor.$value": "0.75",
        "java.util.HashMap.loadFactor.$class": "java.lang.Float",
        "java.util.HashMap.modCount.$type": "int",
        "java.util.HashMap.modCount.$modifiers": "transient volatile",
        "java.util.HashMap.modCount.$value": "1",
        "java.util.HashMap.modCount.$class": "java.lang.Integer",
        "java.util.HashMap.entrySet.$type": "java.util.Set",
        "java.util.HashMap.entrySet.$modifiers": "private transient",
        "java.util.HashMap.entrySet.$size": 1,
        "java.util.HashMap.entrySet.$value": "[Client.Address=127.0.0.1]",
        "java.util.HashMap.entrySet.$class": "java.util.HashMap$EntrySet",
        "java.util.HashMap.serialVersionUID.$type": "long",
        "java.util.HashMap.serialVersionUID.$modifiers": "private static final",
        "java.util.HashMap.serialVersionUID.$value": "362498820763181265",
        "java.util.HashMap.serialVersionUID.$class": "java.lang.Long",
        "java.util.AbstractMap.keySet.$type": "java.util.Set",
        "java.util.AbstractMap.keySet.$modifiers": "transient volatile",
        "java.util.AbstractMap.keySet.$value": "null",
        "java.util.AbstractMap.values.$type": "java.util.Collection",
        "java.util.AbstractMap.values.$modifiers": "transient volatile",
        "java.util.AbstractMap.values.$value": "null"
    }
    "dump.elapsed.ms": 17
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and TNT4J prints all the values set or otherwise. You may want to submit and enhancement request, but i dont think it is supported. all values will be dumped. Keep in mind knowing the variable is there and set to null is important.